# Error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:"

Tags: java

Tengo una clase en la cual le mando los parametros de esta manera y funciona correctamente, el problema esta cuando quiero llenar ese vector automaticamente por medio de un for
[image: Codigo que]

cuando lo quiero llenar coloco el vector de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando lo ejecuto me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que instrucción tienes en el for?, porque probablemente este haciendo ciclos demas.

Comment: ese array no tiene elementos.. tenes que inicializarlo con la cantidad de elementos que queres...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: el problema se debe a que tratas de inicializar pero..es importante agregues el "for" del cual hablas, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Recuerda la definición de un Arreglo (Array) en Java, es un conjunto, que almacena una colección secuencial de tamaño **fijo** de elementos del mismo tipo, en este caso tu tamaño de arreglo es {} por lo cual no puedes almacenar la cantidad de elementos que indicas.

Este tipo de inicialización se recomienda cuando ya tienes lo objetos listos para ser almacenados dentro del arreglo, por ejemplo:

```
Elemento[] elementos = {new Elemento(1,1), new Elemento(1,2)};
```

Necesitas inicializar el arreglo con la cantidad de elementos que piensas almacenar dentro de el, o debido a que piesas almacenar referencias en memoria (Objetos) y no tipos de datos primitivos, debes de comenzar a utliizar collecciones si no sabes la cantidad de elementos que tienes que almacenar.